# how to make multi authentication for admin , user and parents. can anybody help me

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel framework. I'm creating a student management system as a project. I have used the php artisan make:auth command and manage to create two authentication but i am having a issue when creating another one.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://medium.com/hello-laravel/multiple-authentication-system-laravel-5-4-ac94c759638a) which explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to use 'user' and 'admin' two different model to authenticate.

Follow below steps

In Admin Model

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;
   ....
}
```

In defile that model in grade and provider in config/auth.php

```
'guards' =>[
 ......
     'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
     ],
]
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

Open the LoginController in app/Http/Controllers/Auth and edit as follows:

```
 class LoginController extends Controller
 {
  ........
     public function guard()
     {
         return Auth::guard('admin');
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Separate Middlewares for admin,users and parents and define three different middleware groups in routes. piece of cake.